# UIApplicationShortcutIcon only can use image from main bundle?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, bundle, xcasset

Is it true that `UIApplicationShortcutIcon` can only use image from main bundle? I moved my code to a framework and now it stops working.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does look like the asset need to be from the main bundle, the initializer of `UIApplicationShortcutIcon` doesn't let you specify a `Bundle`, and the doc says:

> The name of a custom image in the app’s asset catalog. If the image is not in your app’s asset catalog, this method searches the app bundle for the image.

And from my test it does look like the asset need to be from the main bundle.